# How to install Wordpress/CiviCRM on arvixe hosting server

Tags: installation

I am running WP 4.4.2 trying to install CiviCRM 4.7.1. I get to the point where I enter the URL to run the install script then get a message that I do not have sufficient permsissions to access this page. The CiviCRM instructions say that this could be due to the fact that I deactivated CiviCRM before running the script, but I did not do that. It is activated.

Answer (score 1):

If you've just upgraded CiviCRM for Wordpress and you see this error, check that you've restored the `civicrm.settings.php` file from your previous codebase as per steps 2 & 3 of [Upgrading CiviCRM for WordPress](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Wordpress)

- In step 2 of the upgrade, you make a copy of `wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php`
- In step 3 of the upgrade, you restore this copy to `wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php`

Omitting this, or having a `civicrm.settings.php` which is unreadable to the webserver, may lead to the "you do not have permissions to access this page" error.